# Is this a cold solder joint and do LEDs dim if it is a cold solder?

Tags: led, soldering, wire

[image: Solder joints]

Are the solders in blue cold solders or something else?
They are connected to LEDs and they are glowing dim now, but they used to glow bright when their wires were soldered properly.

Comment: very sloppy soldering ... possibility of a short circuit at the middle blue circle ... what is preventing you from passing the wires through the holes? ... seeing separate strands indicates that the wires were not pre-tinned before soldering to the board

Comment: start over ... work at one connection at a time, so that you do not mix up the wires ... desolder a wire, cut off the end, strip a short length from the end, twist the wire end, apply solder, trim end if it is too long ... clean the pad on the board ... push the wire through the pad if possible ... solder

Comment: The uncircled red wire at the top is defininately a cold solder joint. The others are hard too tell because the workmanship is poor.

Comment: Cold solder joint means the joint has not been heated through enough and the solder is only sticking to the surface. Those solder joints in the picture there are very bad, no flux was used and the solder wasn't sucked into the strand.

Comment: Thanks guys may God bless you all, I will fix the issue using Flux. You can understand that as I am a beginner I made this mistake.

Comment: I also want to know that, does poor soldering cause leds to be dim and not glow at all?

Comment: As well as generally horrifically bad soldering and wire dressing, that wire is not taking the solder well. Maybe it's old and the tinning is all corroded. Normally the solder would run up the strands and wet the wire.

Answer (score 2):

They are poor solder joints, maybe cold solder joints, but poor primarily. You will need to use flux!  I don't see any residue there sir.  Please rework the wiring using flux if you can, or flux core solder if you have at least that.

Comment: Thank you very much sir, as I am a beginner In electronics if was hard for me. I have already ordered Flux core solder may God bless you

Comment: I also want to know that does poor soldering cause leds to dim and also not glow

Answer (score 1):

Yes these are cold, among other things. It's a real hack job.

- Wrong amount of insulation has been peeled. The amount of exposed wire should not be much larger than the surface where it is intended to be soldered.
- After peeling a wire, you should 'collect' the strands to follow the natural twist of the cable. You shouldn't forcibly twist them together, nor should you leave them pointing in every direction as was done here.
- It is highly questionable to route cables across the PCB as in this picture. It might affect EMC and there is a risk of shorts in case some component gets hot and the cable rests against it. The rule of thumb is to never route a cable so that it rests against a component.
- Ideally cables should have some sort of mechanical strain relief so that the solder joints don't take damage unnecessarily.
- The actual soldering is awfully done. Indeed it is cold solder joints, because the solder has not 'wet' across the wires. This happens when either or both metal surfaces to be joined isn't warm enough, or in case there is oxidation/dirt on one of them. In this case the person who did the job didn't know anything about soldering so that's why. Please note that *all* joints where the wires attached look poor, not just the 3 most disastrous that you marked blue.

How to salvage/repair:

- These are in such a bad state that they need to be redone from scratch.
- Heat up each joint and remove the wire. Clean up with a solder wick braid.
- Cut off the bad wires at least 5mm from where the insulation ends currently.
- If possible re-route the cables so that they all enter the board from the right side on the picture.
- Peel approximately 3mm of each wire. This time gently gather the strands with your fingers.
- Apply solder to the peeled wire in advance and let it wet proper.
- Mechanically fix the wires temporarily against the board with tape and similar.
- Solder with a flat chisel tip. Warm the pad for a short moment with the tip before moving it towards where the pad meets the wire. Apply solder, be careful not to heat it too long. If you are inexperienced maybe turn down the temperature to some 250-270°C.
- If you mess up then you can apply external flux and re-heat the joint briefly.

Comment: It also looks like there's a possibility that the wire was moved as the solder was cooling, as it looks grainy and crystallized.  Cold joints can do that do, so it's hard to say which is the culprit, if not both.